# Convert from check_box to radio_button in Rails form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have check_box inside my form like this below. I can select or deselect an item. But what I want is to select only one item from the group of options (items) that I have. How can I do that using radio_button ??

```
      <%= f.fields_for :items, @form_items do |fields| %>
        <% if editable %>
            <%= fields.hidden_field :unit_id %>
            <%= fields.check_box :_destroy, { checked: item.persisted?, class: 'add-item', "data-price" => item.pre_tax_amount, readonly: true }, '0', '1' %>
        <% end %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [collection_radio_button helper](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_radio_buttons) that rails provide using @form_items as the collection.

```
<%= fields.collection_radio_buttons :item, @form_items %>
```

This should give you a starting place; not knowing the contents of the collection makes it difficult to give a full example.